# Replace one variable in Yocto

Tags: yocto

I am using the raspberry pi layer and the IMAGE_CLASSES variable is set this way, I checked doing `bitbake core-image-minimal -e | grep "^IMAGE_CLASSES"`.

I want to modify what is set in `../meta-raspberrypi/conf/machine/include/rpi-default-settings.inc`, which defines how the image is partitioned. I want to avoid to edit this file from the raspberrypi layer.

```
# RaspberryPi BSP default settings

IMAGE_CLASSES += "sdcard_image-rpi"
```

I would like to use my own .class file. I tried creating a layer with a higher priority, the same filename, same location and different content, but still, `bitbake -e` returns the same content. And of course, this layer has been added in the bblayer.conf.

I also tried to add in my local.conf:
`IMAGES_CLASSES_remove += "sdcard_image-rpi"`

Again, no change.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your intention. If you want to override a .class file completely, you can place modified version of it in your custom meta layer, and place your custom layer on top of bblayers.conf (your custom meta should be placed before the one you are overriding class from).

BTW: `IMAGES_CLASSES_remove += "sdcard_image-rpi"` does not look correct: you should either use _append / _remove override or '+=' operator, not both.